# How would I only allow user to input one decimal point in calculator app?

Tags: java

I am creating a calculator for class and I need to restrict the user to add one decimal point. At the current state they can add as many as they want.

I am very new to Java so bear with me..

Here is where the text box is created:

```
public InLab05() {

    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();


    JTextField result = new JTextField();
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.gridwidth = 4;
    add(result, c);
```

Comment: You may get some insight if you search for "input validation" or "validation of user input on JTextField".

Answer (score 0):

On input you can run result.indexOf("."); If it returns -1, then allow the user input to be added, as you know the string does not contain .

Answer (score 0):

use this, it will keep the number with only one decimal digit even if he continue to enter more digits.

```
result.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
  public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    check();
  }
  public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    check();
  }
  public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    check();
  }

  private void check(){
     String str=result.getText();
     if(str.length()- str.lastIndexOf('.')>2){
          result.setText(str.subString(0,str.lastIndexOf('.')+2);
     }
  }
});
```